# Add line break after every </p>

Tags: unix, command-line, sed

I have a bunch of html that has no line breaks. I would like to add a line break or two after any `</p>` tag.

I thought this would do it but it doesn't seem to add blank lines:

```
echo "<p>first line of text</p><p>second line of text</p>" | sed 's:</p>:</p>\n:g' > file.html
```

Comment: Do you just want to generally beautify HTML? A quick Google search gave this, see how it works for you: http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/html-beautifier.html

Comment: With `sed`, it's always helpful to post an OS and/or version!

Comment: @Dan Fego - On a Mac in a bash shell. Can't figure out how to get sed's version number...tried -v,--version and man sed didn't give any hint at it either.

Comment: @minitech - only need to add lines for ease of reading for myself...nothing more...thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because a non-GNU version of `sed` doesn't support `\n`.  A clever way to get around this is to use the `bash` shell to expand it for you before giving it to sed.  This should work for all versions of `sed` as long as you use `bash` as your interpreter

```
$ sed $'s:</p>:&\\\n:g' <<<'<p>first line of text</p><p>second line of text</p>'
<p>first line of text</p>
<p>second line of text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will work for you, but it's a little too long (and needs to be formatted) to put in a comment. You can try putting in an actual newline in, on the command line, by hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and putting in a backslash, to tell `sed` to continue on the next line:

```
echo "<p>first line of text</p><p>second line of text</p>" | sed 's:</p>:</p>\
:g' > file.html
```

Answer (score 0):

The sed version didn't work for me and I'm also on OS X. awk worked:

```
echo "<p>first line of text</p><p>second line of text</p>" | 
awk '{gsub(/<\/p>/,"</p>\n");print $0;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `perl` instead of `sed` when you need to manipulate line endings.  A simple `sed` script like this can be transferred verbatim to `perl -pe` and it'll magically start working:

```
echo "<p>first line of text</p><p>second line of text</p>" | perl -pe 's:</p>:</p>\n:g'
```